# SSH user with specific command execution permission

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to create a user who can log into my server and run the specific command only.

Let say I already have a user **user_xyz** and his home folder is

*/home/user_xyz/*

now inside that home folder, there is another folder public_html folder.

Now I want to add user say **developer** and his home folder is

*/home/user_xyz/public_html*

**developer** user can only be logged in through ssh and can not access outside of its home folder and can only run only below command

1. composer install
2. composer update
3. mkdir

Comment: You can do it by configuring `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, you can set a command for each key. That command would have to handle execing one of the 3.

Comment: Putting a home directory in a home directory seems like a bad idea, and not what you need. You can however use a link from one to the other. `ln -s /home/developer/public_html /home/user_xyz/`. Also check that your file permissions are set up correctly.

Comment: If your user `developer` cannot access anything outside the desired directory, they cannot execute `/bin/mkdir`. You can probably put them into a chroot jail on login, though.

Answer (score 1):

Create your user and use bash's restricted shell `/bin/rbash` for their shell (*).

Now, craft their home directory with only what they need:

- a `bin` directory with the binaries they are allowed to use
- a startup script (`.profile`, etc) that defines `PATH` to be that directory, and that undefines (or redefines) all shell builtins that you don't want them to use

That's the idea.

(*) With only three commands, you may also want to create your own shell.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can set a specific directory as users home directory by below command

```
useradd -d /home/user_xyz/developer developer
```

and for limited command access, open file name as

```
vi /etc/sudoers
```

or simply run command

```
visudo
```

Edit the file, you can find lines to provide control or limited command access to limited user.